# Confused with different metric types

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

When I look at [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html#high-resolution-metrics) I see that there are two types of metrics:

- Standard resolution, with data having a one-minute granularity
- High resolution, with data at a granularity of one second

But when I look at [pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/?nc1=h_ls) I see that there are another two different types of metrics listed:

- Basic Monitoring Metrics (at 5-minute frequency)
- 10 Detailed Monitoring Metrics (at 1-minute frequency)

And when I look lower at pricing I see that all metrics are priced equally e.g:

> First 10,000 metrics $0.30

So as I got it there are 3 types of metrics:

1. Basic Monitoring Metrics (5 min period)
2. Detailed Monitoring/Standard resolution Metrics (1 min period)
3. High resolution Metrics (1 sec period)

And I can use Basic Monitoring Metrics as much as I want for free, 10 Detailed Monitoring/Standard resolution Metrics for free and 0 High resolution Metrics for free. Are my suggestions right?

And what Metric Type do Metric Filters use?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question

Comment: ok, but where should I ask it then?